# Notation Question $K[x]/(p(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $K$ is a field and $p(x)$ is in $K[x]$, I just want to make sure I know what $L = K[x]/(p(x))$ refers to.

Does it refer to the set of all polynomials in $K[x]$ multiplied by $ p(x)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to write (a) for all elements of a ring multiplied by one of it's elements 'a'. This is called the principal ideal generated by that element.  The notation $R /I   $  means quotient ring by 
an ideal I.

Comment: Thanks P! So you're saying that what it refers to is [K(x)]/p(x)K[x]?

Comment: @ThinkConnect yes.